# Angular2 new project is not runnig

Tags: angular

I have already unistalled it and reinstalled angular.
I don't know why but I can run only this project that i downloaded it.
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial
The new projects won't run.
These are the errors when I do npm start:

[image]

Comment: What verison of npm / nodejs are you using ? Did you `npm install`before starting the project ?

Comment: did you `npm install` executed?

Comment: Yes I installed it
npm 4.4.1
node 7.7.2